# Access JSON Object data with space in name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I make an API call and get returned some JSON.  I then parse this JSON using

```
var json = $.parseJSON(result);
```

To get to the level I need to within this json object, I do something like this

```
console.log(json.data[0].value)
```

That will print something like the following to the console

```
Option  "1166325"
Option Two  "3329076"
```

So if I do

```
console.log(json.data[0].value.Option)
```

I am printed out 1166325.  If however I do

```
console.log(json.data[0].value.Option Two)
```

I get an error SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.  I have also tried

```
console.log(json.data[0].value.['Option Two'])
```

But this returns SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

So how can I access this data considering there is a space in the name?

Thanks

Comment: Leave out the dot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just lose the `.` character:

```
console.log(json.data[0].value['Option Two'])
```

This is known as [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) and can always be used to access a property. [Dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) can only be used when the property name is a valid Javascript identifier. This means (a) letters and numbers; (b) `_` underscores; (c) `$` dollar signs.

Comment: Oh wow, dont believe I missed that.  Will mark as correct as soon as it allows me too.  Thanks